# How to add "client_id", "redirect_uri" etc.. parameters to url?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface

Before i access an app on facebook i must allow it (give permisssions). I did this with direct url https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/&scope=publish_actions,user_likes&response_type=code

I can access the app with such url, but by default if i send invitation to some friend and he clicks on the invitation he opens such url :https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=479061678772593&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_request

But in order to work my app needs "client_id" "redirect_uri", "scope" and "response_type" get parameters. How do i pass them to this url? Is it possible to configure something from app settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in order to work my app needs "client_id" "redirect_uri", "scope" and "response_type" get parameters. How do i pass them to this url?

Not at all, because that URL is generated by Facebook.

Maybe you want to enable *Authenticated Referrals*, so that users arriving at your app get prompted to connect to it automatically?

Otherwise you’ll have to call the login URL yourself, by redirecting the user client-side via JavaScript; or just by using FB.login.